# Titanium Twitter App for learning

Tags: twitter, titanium

I'm creating a simple twitter to learn Titanium.  What I have is a tableView populated from a live twitter stream.

What I need to know is how I create clickable links from twitter user names, to be able to open that user's profile.  I can get the regexp'd usernames, but don't know how to do something with them.

Any help much appreciated.

Paul

Comment: Are you still lookinf for a solution to this?

Comment: Hi Camilo_U.  No, I didn't continue with Titanium. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kitchen Sink Application](http://developer.appcelerator.com/doc/kitchensink) has examples of pretty much everything, I would suggest you started there.

Your question(s) are pretty high level and general so, look though the app provided and when you run into specific problems, post those and then the community can respond